# How to create an Option Group in Antd Design?

Tags: reactjs, json, drop-down-menu, antd

I'm trying to implement a categories input with this data returned from my DB

```
[
  {
    _id: '63e59f91bd2a21368188ff4b',
    title: 'Uncategorized',
    slug: 'uncategorized',
    categoryType: 'blog',
    createdAt: '2023-02-10T01:36:17.704Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-02-10T01:36:17.704Z',
  },
  {
    _id: '63e5984028745af5bad2c015',
    parentCategory: {
      _id: '63e5974a786719dd4bb2d37b',
      title: 'Projects',
    },
    title: 'YTDownloader',
    slug: 'ytdownloader',
    categoryType: 'blog',
    createdAt: '2023-02-10T01:05:04.919Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-02-10T01:05:04.919Z',
  },
  {
    _id: '63e597c3786719dd4bb2d387',
    parentCategory: {
      _id: '63e5974a786719dd4bb2d37b',
      title: 'Projects',
    },
    title: 'Song Finder',
    slug: 'song-finder',
    categoryType: 'blog',
    createdAt: '2023-02-10T01:02:59.742Z',
    updatedAt: '2023-02-10T01:02:59.742Z',
  },
]
```

What I'm trying is to create the example given in the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/select?theme=dark&theme=compact) since my categories are pretty much 'parents' or 'childrens' and don't want to have them unorganized.

So far this is what I've been trying but to not success:

```
<Select
  placeholder="Select category"
  defaultValue={category}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setObjectData({
      ...objectData,
      category: e,
    })
  }}
  value={category}
  options={[
    categories.map((c, i) => [
      {
        label: c.parentCategory ? c.parentCategory.title : c.title,
      },
    ]),
  ]}
/>
```

This returns literally nothing, not even an error. What I was expecting is the following:

```
  <Select
    defaultValue={category}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setObjectData({
        ...objectData,
        category: e,
      })
    }}
    value={category}
    options={[
      {
        label: 'Projects',
        options: [
          {
            label: 'YTDownloader',
            value: '63e5984028745af5bad2c015',
          },
          {
            label: 'Song Finder',
            value: '63e597c3786719dd4bb2d387',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        label: 'Uncategorized',
        value: '63e59f91bd2a21368188ff4b'
        ],
      },
    ]}
  />
```

Has anyone done something like this before? It will be great if you guys can help me solve this little issue that's been giving a headache for the last 2 hours, LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```js
<Select
  placeholder="Select category"
  defaultValue={category}
  onChange={(e) => {
    setObjectData({
      ...objectData,
      category: e,
    })
  }}
  value={category}
>
  {categories
    .filter((c) => c.parentCategory === undefined)
    .map((category, index) => (
      <Select.OptGroup key={category._id} label={category.title}>
        {categories
          .filter((c) => c.parentCategory?._id === category._id)
          .map((childC, index) => (
            <Select.Option key={childC._id} value={childC._id}>
              {childC.title}
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
      </Select.OptGroup>
    ))}
</Select>
```

I pretty much had to do two loops instead of one but hey!. This gets the job done, I guess?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be you have only passed objects to `options` that only have a `label` and no `value`. This is speculation, but it's possible nothing is rendered in the dropdown if there is no corresponding `value` to each `label`.

The label, which is what the user sees for each option, isn't necessarily its underlying value.

Keep in mind the `value` is ultimately the thing that will be passed to `onChange`, so to only have a label with no value could explain why it just does nothing -- because a valid option must have a value.

Map each option such that its `value` represents that option uniquely:

```
    categories.map((c, i) => [
      {
        label: c.parentCategory ? c.parentCategory.title : c.title,
        value: c._Id
      },
    ]),
```